# Groovy JDBC: How to update a table with prepared statement where a condition must be met before updating the fields

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, prepared-statement

I am trying to update a table in SQL with a prepared statement, were I need to set a field to a specific value. This is what I have:

```
String sqlString = """UPDATE TIDCNMST
                         SET EDI_OBJECT_MODE = 'E'
                         AND SET EDI_STATUS = 'N'
                       WHERE CONTRACT_STATUS = ?"""
PreparedStatement pstmt = extensionContext.createPreparedStatement(sqlString)
pstmt.setObject(1, contractStatus, OracleTypes.FIXED_CHAR)
pstmt.executeUpdate()
```

Where TIDCNMST is the table name, and EDI_OBJECT_MODE and EDI_STATUS are the fields that need to be updated, and CONTRACT_STATUS is the field that contains the required condition that needs to be met before the fields are updated. For example, a contract must be set to 'cancelled' so that the EDI_OBJECT_MODE should be set to 'E', or "enabled', and then the EDI_STATUS should be set to 'N' so that a vendor doesn't receive the EDI (Electronic Data Interchange). The function to check for the status is = `if (userAction.contains("O06") && (contractStatus != "PENDING" && contractStatus != "APPROVED")){ checkForValidationError(extensionContext, thisPanelState, logger) }`. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `AND SET EDI_STATUS = 'N'`, you should have `, EDI_STATUS = 'N'`...  I'm getting a feeling of deja-vu...  What exactly is the problem you're facing?  I'm struggling to see from the question which bit you're having problems with...  Does the above not work as expected?  How does it not work?  Does it do something wrong?  What _should_ it do instead?

Comment: I had deleted the original question and re-phrased it to be a little clearer. Right now it is not working as expected and it is not updated said fields.